# calling a combination of jquery and php file through script tag

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to call a combination of jQuery and PHP file through script tag but it is not loading properly.

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$("#country").change(function(){
    var getVal = $(this).val();
<?php $sql="select t.term_id,t.description,t2.name,t2.slug from wp_term_taxonomy as t join wp_terms as t2 on t.term_id=t2.term_id where t.parent=3";
$data=mysql_query($sql); 
while($rec=mysql_fetch_array($data))
{?> if(getVal=="<?php echo $rec['name'];?>" )
  {
    window.location = "<?php echo get_category_link( $rec['term_id'] );?>";
  } <?php }?>                           
});
$("#team").change(function(){
    var getVal = $(this).val();
<?php
$args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'taxonomy' => 'teams'
  );
$categories=get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { ?>if(getVal=="<?php echo $category->name;?>"){
<?php $x=str_replace(' ','-',$category->name);
      $y=str_replace('\'','',$x);?>
    window.location = "<?php echo home_url( '/' );?>teams/<?php echo $y;?>";
  }
<?php }?>
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Does anyone else think that this code is an unreadable mess?

Comment: Check your javascript console, do you get any errors?

Comment: after checking console,if it doesn't shows any error,then trace out with alert in each control structure

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that, PHP will be executed when page loads, it wont wait for "change" event.  That is only thing i can see in this mess.

Try to generate jquery with php, that will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Php runs on the server and javascripts run on the client. you cannot combine them this way.

one way is to have the javascripts call the php file using ajax.

See " http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/jquery-ajax-tutorial-example-ajax-jquery-development.html " and " http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ "

so your javascript change event will call via ajax the url the your php script is on. the php script will query the database and output the results as json format back to the javascript. the javascript can basically do anything you want with the results from the php output.